# jquery .css() not working with font-size

Tags: jquery, html

I know that there are a lot of other questions of this type, but none of them gave me my answer. This is throwing no errors, and I cannot see any bug or syntax errors.

I am trying to make a google fonts picker (kind of) using jquery:
js:

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
    var fontFamilyOrig = $("#font").val();
    var prefix = "//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=";
    var fontFamily = fontFamilyOrig.split(' ').join('+');
    fontFamily = prefix + fontFamily;
    var fontSize = $("#font-size").val();
    var displayText = $("#display-text").val();
    var boldToggle = $("#bold");
    var itToggle = $("#italic");
    $("#font-link").attr('href', fontFamily);
    $("#display").css({
        'font-family': fontFamilyOrig,
        'font-size': fontSize
    }).text(displayText);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div>
           <table><tr> <td>Type the name of the font (in full):</td> <td><input type="text" name="font" id="font"></td></tr>
       <tr><td> Type your display text:</td> <td><input type="text" id="display-text"></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Choose a font size:</td><td><input type="number" value="" id="font-size"></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Other options:</td>
                <td>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" id="bold">Bold</label>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" id="italic">Italic</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Go" id="submit"></td>
            </tr>

       </table>
        </div>
        <div id="display">

        </div>
        <link id="font-link" rel="stylesheet" href="">
```

So what this does is display the text the user inputs in the user-specified font and font-size. But the font works, while the font-size does not. Why is only the font working, and not the font-size? 
 [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/zfvooLvv/)

Answer (score 4):

Need to have px or em at the end of font size is my guess. Like you have to say

```
fontSize: fontSize + "px";
```

or

```
fontSize: fontSize + "em";
```

Comment: It's close, I'd add it like so: `'font-size': (fontSize + 'px')`

Comment: Thanks, can't give it the check yet.

Comment: @TimLewis, i just made a variable with the value `px` and the syntax: `.css('font-size', fontSize + otherVariable);`

Comment: @yak613 Yup, that works and is a good idea if you don't plan on only using `px` (ie `em`, etc)